# Problem with cleaning up a thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a server in Java which is multithreading, and I've created a thread pool for it.
Now everything goes well and my server accepts and reads data from the clients that connect to it, but I don't know really how to clean up the sockets after the connections are closed.

So here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ThreadPooledServer server = new ThreadPooledServer(queue,7001);
    new Thread(server).start();
}
```

ThreadPooledServer class:

```
public class ThreadPooledServer implements Runnable {
    protected ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

public ThreadPooledServer(BlockingQueue queue,int port) {
    this.serverPort = port;
    this.queue=queue;
}

    public void run() {
        openServerSocket();

        while (!isStopped()) {
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                clientconnection++;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (isStopped()) {
                    System.out.println("Server Stopped.");
        return;
            }

            throw new RuntimeException("Error accepting client connection", e);
        }

        WorkerRunnable workerRunnable = new WorkerRunnable(queue,clientSocket);

        this.threadPool.execute(workerRunnable);

    }
    this.threadPool.shutdown();

    System.out.println("Server Stopped.");
}

private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
    return this.isStopped;
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    this.isStopped = true;

    try {
        this.serverSocket.close();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
    }
}
```

Here's what I don't understand: My `while()` loop that accepts for clients works as loong as `isStopped` is false.

When `isStopped` is set to true, my loop ends and then I shut down my thread pool, which is correct.

isStopped is set to true in onstop(){..............}....

Where should I call onstop()...?

Because in this moment I'm not using this method ,I'm not calling it and that means that I'm not cleaning correctly my threads.

WorkerRunnable class:

```
    public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable {
        public WorkerRunnable(BlockingQueue queue2, Socket clientSocket2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            this.clientSocket2 = clientSocket2;

            this.queue2 = queue2;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                is = new ObjectInputStream(this.clientSocket2.getInputStream());

                try {
                    while (!stop) {
                        System.out.println("Suntem in interiorul buclei while:!");

                        v = (Coordinate) is.readObject();

                        queue2.put(v);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    is.close();

                    clientSocket2.close();
                }

                is.close();
                clientSocket2.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void stop() {
            this.stop = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have the same issue. How should I clean and close up my sockets correctly?

Comment: -1, you have 65 rep, you should know how to format code blocks on SO by now.

Comment: now I have 63  thanks to you!

Comment: @george, it's too late to cry over spilled milk. I edited your post on your behalf.

Comment: Actually, I've spent the entire 10 minutes since I commented attempting to improve your post. I didn't just do a simple CTRL + K; I cleaned up misaligned braces, problems with spacing, grammar and other issues. But I can see you don't want me here, so I will leave.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus, you really -1 for that?  Give him a break, he at least attempted to format it correctly.

Comment: @John, I wouldn't downvote someone who was brand new, but that's not the case here. Did you look at revision 1? I thought it showed a significant lack of effort.

Comment: Hes been a member for a bit over a week I would give him the benefit of the doubt.  And no, the first revision doesn't look THAT bad.

Comment: Don't fight over that.Honestly,I admit that I don't know how to format my posts!

Comment: @Lord Torgamus u are more than welcome here...no need to leave.U can stay as long as you want too....I don't have anything against you,even if u gave mme -1:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you call `shutdown()` the thread pool will close off each thread once all the tasks are complete.

You should call `onstop()` from whatever code knows the pool should be shutdown.  This depends on what the rest of your application does and why you would stop the pool before the application has finished.

Comment: the method is called stop()....but I think I should call this when my app shuts down so this way I could close all the worker threads!And the other problem is that in WorkerRunnable I use the same tehnique....And I should close my WorkerRunnable when there appears an exception or the other end of my socket is closed!!!!Who do I do that?

Comment: Why do you need to shutdown the threads/socket when you are exiting?  When you exit they will be stopped/closed anyway. When the other end is closed you get an exception which you can catch and close the socket. (Which you appear to be doing already)

Comment: so the stop() method has no role in all this???:-S....What should I improve in this code?:-S

Comment: A shutdown is useful if you want clients to have their connections closed gracefully. However clients should always assume the connection can be lost suddenly.

Comment: I would use standard logging and utility method to handle close() like Apache commons `IOUtils.close()` which will simplify some of your code and ensure you are closing correctly. I wouldn't read your data and place on a queue, I would just process the object in the same thread to simplify your solution (The Socket is a kind of queue anyway)  You might like to ensure your ObjectOutputSTream calls reset() regularly to prevent a memory leak. (Otherwise both ends remember every object they have ever seen, something which will grow and grow over time)

Comment: Which one do you need help with?

Comment: Both...closing correct and simple my sockets and reset the ObjectOutputSTreams:D...I would really appreciate if u would do that for me cause I'm only half competent and I kept asking here but no one helped.Thx:)

Comment: The simplest thing to do is call reset() before or after each object you send.  I suggest you look at the javadoc for IOUtils (google will find it) using it is trivial.

Comment: ok...I called os.reset() on the OutputObjectStream and it was easy...I did it at the other end of the channel.That was easy:).But with the easy closing sockets still not managing:D

Comment: You have to include the library and call `IOUtils.close(socket);` it doesn't get much easier.